# PHP Fundamental Configuration of a CMS

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, content-management-system

My question is very fundamental: The basic idea of a CMS is that there aren't real content files but in the simplest scenario one single file *index.php,* which:

1. reads the URL like *domain.com/fruit/pineapple(.php)* or
   *domain.com?cat=fruit&sort=pineapple,*
2. fills itself with the pineapple-content from a datasource,
3. will be send back then to the client with the alias of the request URL.

**About 1)** How does the server know that *index.php* is in charge for every request? Is it only htaccess? Wordpress:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Is this everything? Every nonexisting file is interpreted as an existing article of the content? So I have to check inside index.php that a forgotten image *pineapple.png* is sorted out?

**About 2)** How does the server rewrite the name *index.php* into */fruit/pineapple(.php)* or *?cat=fruit&sort=pineapple* ? This can't be a 301-rewrite, the server has to rebaptize index.php into the requested URL.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**: Yes, RewriteEngine takes care of routing every call to *index.php*.
Edit: Actually, not *every call*, the lines with `!-f` `!-d` test if the call refers to an existing resource. It only routes to index.php if they don't exist. This allows for the server to send existing files (such as images and other included files, like js and css files) without help from index.php.
So, if I request `domain.com/fruit/pineapple.jpg`, and that image exists, I will get it. if it doesn´t exist, index.php gets called and it may generate a nice looking *404 page*.

**Question 2**: No, this is not taken care by *APACHE*, it is taken care by *index.php* itself, by inspecting $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], and mathing its contents against a set of predefined routes. 
This is called *URL Routing*. Each CMS has its own way of doing this, and there are also some libraries for PHP (or any other server-side language you prefer).

You can take a look at a longer explanation about [How to Implement URL Routing in PHP](http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/05/21/how-to-implement-url-routing-in-php/)

Comment: Thanks! This approach would never have crossed my mind :)

Comment: If I answered your question, you may consider selecting it as the answer to your question, so that others who have the same doubts may find it.

Comment: Sorry, I am not allowed to vote yet. In the meantime I have completed my handler script and it works well. One huge advantage is that I can control a lot of things much better with PHP than with an htaccess file. Error pages come to mind. The header part was a little bit tricky. And the main directory looks pretty clean :)